# running code on exit from application in tcl

Tags: tcl, exit, tk-toolkit

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to send some code on exit from a tcl application i.e when you press the X in the top right corner please?

I want to be able to turn off any relays that are left on before the app closes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`wm protocol`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M58) command to set a callback when the toplevel window is to be deleted:

```
package require Tk
label .msg -text "click the X"
pack .msg
proc shutdown {} {
    puts "goodbye cruel world"
    exit
}
wm protocol . WM_DELETE_WINDOW shutdown
```

Comment: Hey @kenny, I notice you have zero accepted answers for your questions. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and support the people who are helping you.

Comment: Hey glenn, sorry mate I didn't realise. I'll go through all my questions and do this. Thanks for telling me.